# Exception on insert statement to azure table

Tags: c#, azure-table-storage

I'm getting exception Could not load file or assembly 'System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives, Version=4.0.1.0,
 Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

When I try to insert data.
Solution type is web api 2.
I don't have this library version on my console app.

About code

```
            TableOperation insertOrMergeOperation = TableOperation.InsertOrMerge(entity);

            //public TEntity Add(TEntity entity)
            //{
            //  TableOperation insertOrMergeOperation = TableOperation.InsertOrMerge(entity);
            //  TableResult result = await Set.ExecuteAsync(insertOrMergeOperation);
            try
            {
                var item = await Set.ExecuteAsync(insertOrMergeOperation);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Could you please provide more code? and the package version of azure storage sdk you're using. And are you writing this code in web api 2?